# Why is restricted_package_name used?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html), `restricted_package_name` means:

> This parameter specifies a string containing the package name of your application. When set, messages are only sent to registration IDs that match the package name. Optional.

But aren't registration IDs matched regardless we specify the field? What could be a use case for `restricted_package_name`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, messages are not restricted to application `packageId` by default, which means app with any packageId can receive your messages as long as it knows your `GCM Sender ID` and as long as you use its  `GCM registration Id` as message receipient id. This is not a problem usually - most likely you do additional checks in your middle layer that handles apps' sender id registrations, but if you think you want more control, or want to do selective sending, then you can use `restricted_package_name` to narrow down receipients of your message.

Comment: Is `restricted_package_name` platform specific, will it work on iOS bundle identifier? Thanks